# I have proxmox installed on another computer, I can login on my browser from my ubuntu 22.04. I cannot hear anything from my proxmox vm's

Tags: sound

This is my system that i am accessing proxmox through my browser, I have no sound from the vm's in my browser, I am sorry if this is a stupid question but, I have looked everywhere and I am scared to edit any sys files before coming here and asking for advice. Thank you in advance.
HP HP Pavilion Laptop 15-cw0xxx
AMD® Ryzen 3 2200u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 4
RAVEN (raven, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-46-generic)

Comment: Do you get sound if you login to your VM in proxmox using the app **Virtual Machine Manager** in your Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: honestly, I haven't tried that, would that be like a RDP or something?

Comment: It uses QEMU+SSH I think, so not RDP. You connect the app (VMM) using the IP address of your Proxmox server. The app will show all the VMs you have installed there. Then you can control all the VMs from the VMM app.

Comment: O.k. so just download VMM? Ill give it a shot. thank you. I'll post if that solved it or not. Thank you again.

Comment: it says unable to connect it says something about ssh keys or install SSH askpass locally?

Comment: ok, I got vmm to connect but, now I am not seeing the machine that I'm connected to, it just shows connection details but no image of the actual ubuntu vm that it's connected to. What am i missing? Thanks in advance to all

Comment: Please ask a new question.